# QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS output directory, msvc

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

In a Qt project using msvc2013, I have one .cpp which has to be built with the custom option /arch:IA32 and the preprocessor command _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.

Here is the interesting part a my .pro file:

```
CONFIG(release, debug|release){
    DESTDIR = RELEASE
    OBJECTS_DIR = RELEASE/.obj
    MOC_DIR = RELEASE/.moc
    RCC_DIR = RELEASE/.rcc
    UI_DIR = RELEASE/.ui
}
CONFIG(debug, debug|release){
    DESTDIR = DEBUG
    OBJECTS_DIR = DEBUG/.obj
    MOC_DIR = DEBUG/.moc
    RCC_DIR = DEBUG/.rcc
    UI_DIR = DEBUG/.ui
}

(...)

SPECIAL_SOURCE = extractor.cpp
ExtraCompiler.input = SPECIAL_SOURCE
ExtraCompiler.variable_out = OBJECTS
ExtraCompiler.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${QMAKE_EXT_OBJ}
ExtraCompiler.commands = $${QMAKE_CXX} $(CXXFLAGS) /arch:IA32 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS $(INCPATH) -c ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += ExtraCompiler
```

The problem I got is that the object created - which is "extractor.obj" - is not placed in the same directory than the others. The directory can either be RELEASE/.obj or DEBUG/.obj. Instead of this, "extractor.obj" is created in the root directory, just next my .pro file.

This system worked with other compilers such as MinGW, Clang or GCC. I don't know what is wrong here. Has anyone encountered the same problem?
Thanks a lot.

---

**Edit: two solutions found**

**Solution 1:** change ExtraCompiler.output for windows build (release and debug)

```
SPECIAL_SOURCE = extractor.cpp
ExtraCompiler.input = SPECIAL_SOURCE
ExtraCompiler.variable_out = OBJECTS
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release):    ExtraCompiler.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}release/${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${QMAKE_EXT_OBJ}
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): ExtraCompiler.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}debug/${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${QMAKE_EXT_OBJ}
else:                                    ExtraCompiler.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${QMAKE_EXT_OBJ}
ExtraCompiler.commands = $${QMAKE_CXX} $(CXXFLAGS) -arch:IA32 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS $(INCPATH) -c ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -o ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
```

**Solution 2:** specify the output folder with -Fo instead of -o (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb8e9b8y.aspx)

```
SPECIAL_SOURCE = extractor.cpp
ExtraCompiler.input = SPECIAL_SOURCE
ExtraCompiler.variable_out = OBJECTS
ExtraCompiler.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${QMAKE_EXT_OBJ}
ExtraCompiler.commands = $${QMAKE_CXX} $(CXXFLAGS) -arch:IA32 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS $(INCPATH) -c ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -Fo${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Idea 1**

MSVC places object files usually into a release/debug sub-directory of the build dir. The other compilers don't.

Thus you just have to add `release/` or `debug/` between `${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}` and `${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}`, e.g.

```
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release):    ExtraCompiler.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}release/${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${QMAKE_EXT_OBJ}
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): ExtraCompiler.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}debug/${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${QMAKE_EXT_OBJ}
else:                                    ExtraCompiler.output = ${QMAKE_VAR_OBJECTS_DIR}${QMAKE_FILE_IN_BASE}$${QMAKE_EXT_OBJ}
```

**Idea 2**

Your `ExtraCompiler.input` is empty because when you use custom-defined qmake variables, you need to add `$$` when you use them. Try

```
SPECIAL_SOURCE = extractor.cpp
ExtraCompiler.input = $$SPECIAL_SOURCE
```

Now check whether there is something between `/` and `.obj` in your error message.

Comment: It's not working, the .obj is still created next to the .pro file. The linker try now to find it in the directory RELEASE/.obj/release, which is empty

Comment: @Mezzo okay, your basename was missing in front of `.obj`. I updated the answer. Can you check again?

Comment: Thanks a lot it works! Adding "$$" is not necessary, there is no changes. I found another solution when playing with the compiler attribute: I used `ExtraCompiler.commands = $${QMAKE_CXX} $(CXXFLAGS) -arch:IA32 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS $(INCPATH) -c ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -Fo${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}` (note the -Fo entry)